# !!(new Number(0)) == true, but !!(Number(0)) == false, why?

Tags: javascript, casting, comparison, boolean-operations

Why do the last two behave differently (tested on Google Chrome's console)?

```
               /* number */                       /* string */
         0               == false;         ''               == false;
         !!0             == false;         !!''             == false;
         Number(0)       == false;         String('')       == false;
         !!Number(0)     == false;         !!String('')     == false;
         new Number(0)   == false;         new String('')   == false;
         (new Number(0)) == false;         (new String('')) == false;
         !!new Number(0) == true;          !!new String('') == true;
```

In other words, why is casting to boolean different if `Number` or `String` are called with the new keyword (While e.g., `Array()` and `new Array()` work identically)?

Also, bonus question. Why is `'' == 0`? I would expect that comparison to implicitly cast `0` to `'0'`, since it would be a *widening* conversion, while casting both to booleans before the comparison is a *narrowing* conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `new Number(0)` returns a `Number` object, which is truthy regardless of its value. Therefore, `!!(true) == true`.
- `Number(0)` returns the number `0`, which is falsey: `!!(false) == false`

As for your bonus question, `''` gets cast to an integer when you use the double equals sign. `parseInt('') == 0`.

Comment: I see. I thought both whould return objects... must have let it slip.

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect `''` to be cast to integer. I thought both were cast to booleans! (More 5 min. and I can accept your answer)

Comment: The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) explains the conversion rules. There are special cases for strings and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

`new` gives you an object. Hence the comparison.

Comment: I see. But `Array()` gives me an array Object, I take it `Number()` and `String()` work differently?

Comment: But objects behave differently - for example this dog behaves different to the cat.

Comment: @CamiloMartin `number`s and `string`s in JavaScript are typically scalar values. If you call a method on a string, it's converted to an object for the time it takes to perform the function, and then it turns back into a string. Constructing their objects is the only real way around that. So the reason is simply because unless they are explicitly constructed, strings and numbers are kept as scalars. `0 === false` and `{} === true`.

Comment: @Norguard I see. Is null an object? Because, `typeof null === 'object'`... but `null == false`... It's confusing.

Comment: @CamiloMartin JS is plenty confusing with this stuff... Null ***is*** an object, technically, but it's also a special case, which *always* casts to false. If you want something weirder, `NaN !== NaN;`

Comment: @Norguard Argh, javascript is weird! It's versatile and flexible, nonetheless very weird. But its mind-bending differences to other mainstream languages make it so much more interesting to learn about.